# system requirement

Tags: software-recommendation, kubuntu, xubuntu

My laptop developed a bad sectors and not working well. It was with ubutuntu 12.04 LTS operating system. Now, I want to install ubuntu in an relatively old desktop with the following specifications

Hp compaq dx 2390

Intel ® Pentium Dual Core CPU, E2180 @ 2.00 GHZ, 1.20 GHz, 1 GB Ram, 160 GB Hard Drive

Which k/x/ubuntu version is suitable to this desktop?

PS. I am working in my final thesis and I need a stable k/x/ubuntu to this specification. 
Thank u

Comment: I would install Xubuntu or Lubuntu, Kubuntu and Ubuntu wouldn't work well with an old graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the latest Ubuntu version or 12.04.1 LTS, would work fine on your laptop if you had at least 2Gb of Ram. Consider upgrading.

In the meantime I would try Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Xubuntu is based on the XFCE window manager which is lighter than Gnome/Unity.
Lubuntu is based on the LXDE window manager and is ever lighter than Xubuntu. See [this link](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Lubuntu_vs_Xubuntu) for a comparision of the two.

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer. As K/X/Ubuntu has KDE/XFCE/Gnome looking desktops, what is the looking in the case of Lubuntu? Is Lubuntu also a recommended one to low spec computers? If it is the case, Shall I go to Lubuntu 12.04 LTS? ( As my Desktop has low specs i am thinking to install Xubuntu or ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Shall I go also to Lubuntu 10.04?)

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: If this answer is the right one, why not mark it as the correct one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Xubuntu for this, due to its low load and stability, although Kubuntu shoudl be fine, if you really wanted that.

I might actually recommend Lubuntu, however, since you only have one Gig of RAM. If you got yourself another Gig or so, you should actually be able to run good old Ubuntu just fine.